# MYSQL reference table from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm new to SQL. As an example is my main table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main`.`item` (
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incrementing item_id of each job, unique index',
  `item_title` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'item title, not-unique',
  `item_status`
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='item data';
```

And my reference table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `main`.`status` (
  `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incrementing status_id of each status, unique index',
  `status_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'status name, unique',
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci COMMENT='status';
```

How can I reference the main table to an ID of the status table, so there is a status associated with the main item.

Also since this is my first DB, if I have made any other mistakes please feel free to highlight them.

Answer (score 2):

Your main table should have a status_id column. That column should be designated as a foreign key, and linked to the primary key of the status table.

This will make the item_status column of your main table unnecessary. Use the status_id value from the main table to look up the primary key of the status table on your front end.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. So should I do something like this:
````FOREIGN KEY (status_id) REFERENCES status(id)

Answer (score 0):

Simple:

```
SELECT * FROM main.item, main.status 
           where main.item.item_status = main.status.status_id
```

This will join all rows form `item` with all rows from `status` where there's a matching id. It will not give you any rows where there's an `item_status` which is unknown in table `status`!

You should only keep the last creation of your table item_status.

Comment: OP should also have a look at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Rather use joins than where syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018822/inner-join-on-vs-where-clause